# Does jQuery work on the PSP

Tags: jquery, playstation-portable

How well does the jQuery library work on a PSP?

Comment: Haven't had much luck on any mobile devices save the iPhone...test it and let us know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From John Resig [here](http://www.nabble.com/Playstation-3-td22658905s27240.html)

> " If I remember correctly - the NetFront
>   browser was missing some fairly
>   fundamental features. I don't remember
>   which, off-hand, but it was enough to
>   cause jQuery not even to load."